# How does 'this' keyword resolve in a function call

Tags: javascript

This is probably a typical question for someone new to Javascript. I did research a number of similar questions but wasn't able to explain the behavior that I am seeing.

The code below should illustrate what I am trying to do. I have 2 objects MyObjectA and MyObjectB.

MyObjectB has a method `echo` that simply logs a message. It prefixes the `this.name` to the message in an attempt to know who is executing the method. It also prints the value of `this`.

MyObjectA has a method called `callAFunctionWithMessage` which does exactly that. It accepts a message and a function and calls it.

In the global scope , the objects are instantiated and called. What I see is `this.name` is `undefined`. And the `this` had the value `DOMWindowObject` when executed in the browser and some massive infrastructure-like object when executing in nodejs.  Can someone help me with some insight on this behavior? Given that MyObjectA is calling echo, i expected 'this' to point to MyObjectA.

I also, execute `MyObjectB.echo('hello')` where `this` points to to MyObjectB as expected.

```
function MyObjectA(name) {
    this.name=name;
}

MyObjectA.prototype = {
    name : "",
    callAFunctionWithMessage: function (msg, callback) {
        callback(msg);
    }
}

function MyObjectB(name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

MyObjectB.prototype = {
    name :"",
    echo: function(msg) {
        var messageToPrint='[from '+this.name+']'+msg;
        console.log(messageToPrint, " : " + this);
    }
}

var a = new MyObjectA("ObjA");
var b = new MyObjectB("objB");

a.callAFunctionWithMessage('hello from A!', b.echo);
// => [from result]hello from A! : [object Window]

b.echo('hello!');
// => [from objB]hello! : [object Object]
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do:

```
a.callAFunctionWithMessage('hello from A!', b.echo);
```

the function `b.echo` is getting passed with a global context (window in your case). so `this.name` is not going to be the name property of the object `a` but it will be of the `name` property of the global context, hence you see it as undefined. You can instead change it to call with the context of `a` itself using **[function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)**

```
 a.callAFunctionWithMessage('hello from A!', b.echo.bind(a)); //now you set the callback with the context of b itself.
```

In your case when inside the callback method `this` would represent the global scope.

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bL7hG/)**

Or change the way you invoke your callback by setting a context of current, to ensure that it takes a context of no context is bound to it.

```
MyObjectA.prototype = {
    name : "",
    callAFunctionWithMessage: function (msg, callback) {
        callback.call(this, msg);
    }
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwSHe/)**

Answer (score 2):

When you pass `b.echo` as a callback you pass the function which looses it's context. There are a few simple rules to know what `this` will mean.

1. In a object context it will refer to the object instance.
2. Outside the object context it will be either the global object (Window) or `undefined` depending on strict mode.
3. If strict mode is in effect `this` will not automatically resolve to the global object. It will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` will change depending on how a *function* is invoked, i.e. what context is it given at invoke time? The only exception to this are [*bound functions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

I hope the following example will aid your understanding, along with the [MDN page for **`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this);
}

var bar = {
    'foo': foo,
    'baz': function () {foo();}
};

foo();       // -- logs the global object
             //    `foo` was called without context
bar.foo();   // -- logs `bar`
             //    `foo` was called with context `bar`
bar.baz();   // -- logs the global object
             //    `baz` (in context `bar`) called `foo` without context
var x = bar.foo;
x();         // -- logs the global object
             //    `x` was called without context, `x` is still `foo`
x.call(bar); // -- logs `bar`
             //    `x` was called with context `bar`
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Instead, this offers a puzzle which possibly leads to an answer. Possibly.

Comment: @WiktorZychla The question is `Can someone help me with some insight on this behavior?`, this shows exactly what happens depending on how the function was invoked, and then says the context, so I'm not sure what you mean by a "puzzle". I'll try to clarify what I'm trying to show by adding an extra couple lines.

Comment: Thank you.. This helps very much! I thought bar.baz() would have this pointing to bar because foo is called from bar.. But i get it now. The context is set to the object only if it is invoked as its method..